# Какую выбрать лицензию из LGPL v3 и Apache v2?

Tags: лицензирование

Не могу выбрать между лицензией LGPL v3 и Apache v2 для своего проекта, прошу помощи. Возможно посоветуете другую.

Проект состоит из 2 частей: на PHP и Си. Первая часть та, что на php использует библиотеку под лицензией GNU/LGPL, та что на СИ штатные библиотеки (string,pcre,mysql).

Что хотелось бы от лицензии:

1. название проекта не хотелось бы, чтобы изменяли, если будут копировать/модифицировать/распространять. Если сделают форк, ну что поделать)
2. проект свободный, но в будущем вдруг понадобится сделать расширенную версию из имеющейся, но уже закрытую (скажем для продажи).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LGPL ограничит применение вашей библиотеки в коммерческих проектах, потому что при изменении кода самой библиотеки произойдёт заражение части кода со всеми вытекающими GPL-ными последствиями. Лицензия Apache 2 таким ограничением не обладает, она пермиссивная. Поэтому, если вы хотите максимального распространения библиотеки, то стоит отдать предпочтение Apache 2.

Накладываемые LGPL требования на распространение изменённых версий библиотеки заставить выполнять достаточно затруднительно, а уж на одной шестой части суши — тем более. То есть как достоинство я бы это в принципе не рассматривал.

Учитывая, что все форки будут ссылаться на вас, проблем с изменением названия не вижу. Скажем, если форк разовьётся во что-то совершенно новое, то будет странно требовать сохранения названия, это только вызовет путаницу. Да и как объём изменений регламентировать?

Ни одна лицензия никак не ограничивает ваших прав использовать свой код как хочется и менять лицензию последующих версий на любую другую. Только использование LGPL может выйти боком, потому что в случае пулл-реквестов автором будете не вы один, и нужно будет спрашивать у всех разрешение, нельзя будет в одностороннем порядке полностью закрыть их код и забрать себе, лицензия не позволит. Можно заранее требовать согласие... в общем, всё сложно.

P. S. IANAL.

Comment: а эти обе лицензии требует выкладывания исходником скажем на github? Планировалось все таки выпустить продукт как свободно-распространяемое, а не как opensource. Т.е. код будет закрыт.

Comment: @nerik Тогда при чём здесь форки? о_О Вы уж определитесь: или опен-сорс, или EULA и всё такое.

Comment: про форки думал когда задавал вопрос. Теперь планирую все таки закрыть код, но давать.бесплатно. Если проект понравится то уже делать расширенную платную версию.

Comment: @Discord , главная ошибка в вашем ответе: использование определения «коммерческий» как синонима определению «проприетарный». это **не** синонимы.